# passing clipboard contents to python script run from the command line

Tags: python, macos, command-line, terminal, pipe

I'm trying to pass the contents of the clipboard available to `Terminal` as an argument to a python script. The script is called `tabulate_from_cl.py`, and it simply prints the arguments it receives. Although it executes with no problems there's no sign of the output from `pbpaste`

```
# ------------------------
# tabulate_from_cl.py

import sys

def main(args):
    for each in args:
        print('arg: {}\n'.format(each))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[:])

# ------------------------ 


# lets say pbpaste contains the string 'I am residing on the clipboard'

# at the command line...
$ pbpaste | tabulate_from_cl.py


# actual output
/Users/myhomedirectroy/Desktop/tabulate_from_cl.py

# desired output
/Users/myhomedirectroy/Desktop/tabulate_from_cl.py
I am residing on the clipboard
```

I've tried lots of variations on this, including putting the contents of `pbpaste` into a shell variable, but nothing has yielded the desired output. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

Change your pipe execution as:

```
python tabulate_from_cl.py | pbpaste
```

Comment: This was one of the variations that I tried, but it returns the following error: ``BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe') in <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> ignored``